# {project}.resouces.dll not used when project is referenced as dll

Tags: c#, .net, resx

I have:

- projectA (COM dll)
- en/projectA.resources.dll
- projectB (dll) referenced by projectA
- en/projectB.resources.dll

When i use the projectA GUI is localized, but GUI in the referenced projectB dll is not. why that?
What can i do to get projectB used projectB.resources.dll?

Comment: "Satellite-resources" should be located in subfolders named after their culture (e.g. `\bin\Debug\en-US` and `\bin\Debug\de-DE`). How are you loading resources, exactly? Are you using `.resx` files or separate binary Resource Streams?

Comment: Im doing the localization by using the .resx for each form. (i.e x.en.resx.). then visual studio create a project.resources.dll

Answer (score 0):

Use all the dll in the projectA Build and all the code in the same thread will be localized correctly